# iOS 11 custom titleView size; autolayout seems to be ignored

Tags: ios, uikit, ios11

I have a uinavigationbar as part of a navigationcontroller that I need to be 70 pixels high. Pre-iOS11 there are various solutions and I implemented one.

During the iOS 11 beta, I tried various ways of using autolayout to size the titleView. According to the WWDC talk, it should recognize width+height constraints within the titleview and accommodate them. It does not appear to do so.

It looks like it conflicts with the built in UILayoutGuide

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000008c760 UILayoutGuide:0x6000001acbe0'TitleView(0x7fe600c0a710)'.height == 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61400008c6c0 EasyRelease.CustomTitleView:0x7fe606008e70.top >= UILayoutGuide:0x6000001acbe0'TitleView(0x7fe600c0a710)'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61400008c800 EasyRelease.CustomTitleView:0x7fe606008e70.centerY == UILayoutGuide:0x6000001acbe0'TitleView(0x7fe600c0a710)'.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61400008bbd0 EasyRelease.CustomTitleView:0x7fe606008e70.height == 70   (active)>"
)
```

What gives? Is this feature not implemented correctly in iOS11, or am I missing something? Are there any known workarounds for adjusting titleview+uinavigationbar height?

edit: The way my code works, is I have added width + height constraints to the titleView. Is there anything else I should do? From the WWDC presentation this looked sufficient.

Comment: If you want assistance you will need to detail how your current code works. However, all bugs (especially in beta software) should be reported to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, I believe that it's a bug in iOS. I submitted a bug report and example project to Apple, they thanked me and I have not heard back since that. My solution was to not rely on the uinavigationcontroller's navigationbar and instead instantiate my own navigationbar in each viewcontroller, setting its frame manually.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answer's here: [iOS 11 navigationItem.titleView Width Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932084/ios-11-navigationitem-titleview-width-not-set)

I had a similar problem and overriding "intrinsicContentSize" lead me to the fix.

Comment: Remember to upvote "gngrwzrd" question/answer if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

This could work, it put a view above the NavigationBar.
You should note that your image should be 70 pixels height. 
13 is a magic number for 70 pixels image, because it appears centered in the navigation bar.

```
-(void)updateNavBarBackground{
    [[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
    UIImage * image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarImage"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width  / 2,
                               self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height / 2 - 13);

    imageView.tag = 1;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview : imageView];
}
```