# UISplitViewController: titleView in DetailViewController disappears on landscape orientation, intended behaviour?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm adding a custom `titleView` inside a navigation bar using `navigationItem.titleView` for both Master/Detail VC. On changing the orientation of the device to landscape, `titleView` under `MasterViewController` works fine, but for `DetailViewController` `titleView` disappears. On changing the orientation back to portrait `titleView` appears back for `DetailViewController`. I have also attached a link for source code and video.

Is this an intended behavior or am I making a mistake from my side or is it an issue from Apple's side ?

```
//Custom Title View:
class TitleView: UIView {
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 20)
    }
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       //Adding titleView for Master/Detail VC:
       navigationItem.titleView = {
            //Setting frame size here, did not make any difference
            let view = TitleView(frame: .zero)
            view.backgroundColor = .red
            return view
       }()
    }
}
```

Full source code here: https://github.com/avitron01/SplitViewControllerIssue/tree/master/MathMonsters

Video highlighting the issue: 
https://vimeo.com/336288580

Comment: Seems like this post turned out to be a dud :(

Comment: Similar issue can be observed when the app is running on iPad in multitasking env (with another app side by side). When you change the app to compact and back to regular width the custom title view is gone.

Comment: Wondering if you found a reasonable solution for this? Having the same problem on iOS 13

Comment: Still seeing this issue in iOS 17.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It seems an iOS bug. My workaround was to reassign the title view on every view layout. I used this piece of code in my `DetailViewController`:

```swift
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if let v = navigationItem.titleView {
        navigationItem.titleView = nil
        navigationItem.titleView = v
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. It works for my case where the app is in multitask mode on iPad and the custom title view on DetailViewController will disappear when it's toggled between compact/regular modes.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble upon this, see also [iOS 11 navigationItem.titleView Width Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932084/ios-11-navigationitem-titleview-width-not-set). Basically, there's two suggested workarounds:

- use a custom UIView that tells iOS to treat its `intrinsicContentSize` to be as big as possible with [UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622532-layoutfittingexpandedsize)
- use `widthAnchor`/`heightAnchor` constraints to set width and height of your view